# Modify the legend of pandas bar plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am always bothered when I make a bar plot with pandas and I want to change the names of the labels in the legend. Consider for instance the output of this code:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.pyplot import *

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':26, 'B':20}, index=['N'])
df.plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]
Now, if I want to change the name in the legend, I would usually try to do:

```
legend(['AAA', 'BBB'])
```

But I end up with this:

[image]

In fact, the first dashed line seems to correspond to an additional patch.

So I wonder if there is a simple trick here to change the labels, or do I need to plot each of the columns independently with matplotlib and set the labels myself. Thanks.

Comment: What version of each are you using, `python`, `pandas`, and `matplotlib`. I don't see that problem when I run mine.

Comment: python : 2.7
matplotlib : 1.3.1
pandas : 0.13.1

Comment: Can you try `legend(df.columns)`

Comment: Same result than the second one (with 'A' and 'B' as labels, obviously)

Comment: Ok, I was just testing to see if you specify `legend()` was the cause, since it's working fine for me, and it seems that it is. Would upgrading matplotlib and pandas be an issue?

Comment: No, actually I was thinking about upgrading matplotlib for other reasons. I will get back to you when it's done (thanks for the help).

Comment: Ok, going to pandas 0.17 solved the problem, thanks. Shall I edit the question with the solution?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

To change the labels for Pandas `df.plot()` use `ax.legend([...])`:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':26, 'B':20}, index=['N'])
df.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax)
#ax = df.plot(kind='bar') # "same" as above
ax.legend(["AAA", "BBB"]);
```

[image]

Another approach is to do the same by `plt.legend([...])`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df.plot(kind='bar')
plt.legend(["AAA", "BBB"]);
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! I know this is nearly five years old, but I was wondering if you happened to know the colors you used for the chart? I really love them and can't seem to quite match them, thanks!

Comment: @RichardRobinson The colors are '348ABD','7A68A6','A60628','467821','CF4457','188487','E24A33', The proper way to use them is through `matplotlibrc` config file. If you try google you will find many nice readily available configs.

Answer (score 24):

If you need to call plot multiply times, you can also use the "label" argument:

```
ax = df1.plot(label='df1', y='y_var')
ax = df2.plot(label='df2', y='y_var')
```

While this is not the case in the OP question, this can be helpful if the `DataFrame` is in long format and you use `groupby` before plotting.

Comment: This will work only if you mention the column as y argument.

Answer (score 19):

This is slightly an edge case but I think it can add some value to the other answers.

If you add more details to the graph (say an annotation or a line) you'll soon discover that it is relevant when you call legend on the axis: if you call it at the bottom of the script it will capture different handles for the legend elements, messing everything.

For instance the following script:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':26, 'B':20}, index=['N'])
ax = df.plot(kind='bar')
ax.hlines(23, -.5,.5, linestyles='dashed')
ax.annotate('average',(-0.4,23.5))

ax.legend(["AAA", "BBB"]); #quickfix: move this at the third line
```

Will give you this figure, which is wrong:
[image]

While this is a toy example that can be easily fixed by changing the order of the commands, sometimes you'll need to modify the legend after *several* operations and hence the next method will give you more flexibility. Here for instance I've also changed the fontsize and position of the legend:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':26, 'B':20}, index=['N'])
ax = df.plot(kind='bar')
ax.hlines(23, -.5,.5, linestyles='dashed')
ax.annotate('average',(-0.4,23.5))
ax.legend(["AAA", "BBB"]);

# do potentially more stuff here

h,l = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(h[:2],["AAA", "BBB"], loc=3, fontsize=12)
```

This is what you'll get:

[image]