# Change label names Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I've set the labels in my plots to the labels I want to see in my chart, but it's not working:

```
sns.set(rc={"figure.figsize": (16, 8)})
ax = events_all_metrics[["event_name","kambi_payback"]].plot(x="event_name", style='.',use_index=False, color ='green', label='Kambi Payback')
events_all_metrics[["event_name","pinny_payback"]].plot(x="event_name",style='.', color='red', label='Pinnacle Payback', ax=ax)
plt.tick_params(
    axis='x',          # changes apply to the x-axis
    which='both',      # both major and minor ticks are affected
    bottom='off',      # ticks along the bottom edge are off
    top='off',         # ticks along the top edge are off
    labelbottom='off')
plt.legend(loc=4, prop={'size': 15})

pinny_mean = events_all_metrics["pinny_payback"].mean()
plt.axhline(y=pinny_mean, label='Pinny Mean', linestyle='--', color='red')

kambi_mean = events_all_metrics["kambi_payback"].mean()
plt.axhline(y=kambi_mean, label='Kambi Mean', linestyle='--', color='green')
plt.show()
```

[image: kambi_pinny]

So, I figured out that basically plt.legend() was overwriting the initial labels in pandas. I passed it to the end (just before plt.show() ) with the following code and it worked:

```
plt.legend(["Kambi Payback","Pinnacle Payback", "Kambi Mean", "Pinnacle Mean"], loc=4, prop={'size': 15})
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like pandas overrides the label command when plotting from a DataFrame.  See the example below--the top figure is drawn directly from pandas with `DataFrame.plot(x=...)` while the bottom goes through matplotlib directly with `plt.plot()`.

Directly plotting a series, e.g. `df["series1"].plot()` also does not override the label.

Apparently [this was a behavior known as an issue in an old version of pandas](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9542)--so is it possible it has not been fixed? I can reproduce OP's issue with 0.20.1.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = list(zip(np.arange(100),np.random.random(100),2*np.random.random(100)))

fig,axes = plt.subplots(2,1)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["x","series1","series2"])
df[["x","series1"]].plot(x = "x", color = "red", label = "Label 1", ax = axes[0])

#df[["x","series2"]].plot(x = "x", color = "green", label = "Label 2", ax = ax)

axes[1].plot(df["x"], df["series1"], color = "red", label = "Label 1")

plt.legend()
```

[image]

However, it is possible to rename them after the fact, credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149428/modify-the-legend-of-pandas-bar-plot).  For example:

```
ax = df[["x","series1"]].plot(x = "x", color = "red", label = "Label 1")
ax.legend(["Label 1"])
```

[image]

Still unclear to me whether the inability to set series labels directly during the call to `df.plot()` is intentional or not.

Comment: thanks Patrick. so should I just wait for a fix in the future?

Comment: @IvoFilipe well I've updated the answer to link to a work around for now, but I don't know if a fix to change the core behavior is in the cards or not.  Hope that helps at least.

Comment: @IvoFilipe Can you please accept those answers to any question of yours, if they solve the issue, such that they will not stay unsolved?! Else you may of course ask for clarifications.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I tried the above solution with "ax.legend(["AAA", "BBB"])" in the end but it still didn't work...

Comment: @ivofilipe can you edit your question to incorporate your new code then?

Comment: @PatrickO'Connor I've figured out the problem. I've edited my question with the solution. Thanks!