# how to find mean for mixed categorical variables in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have survey dataset about different age of people over using various social media platform. I want to calculate the average number of people over social media app usage. Here is how example data looks like:

[image]

here is reproducible pandas dataframe:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'age': np.random.randint(10,100,size=10),
                'web1a': np.random.choice([1, 2], size=(10,)),
                'web1b': np.random.choice([1, 2], size=(10,), p=[1./3, 2./3]),
                'web1c': np.random.choice([1, 2], size=(10,)),
                'web1d': np.random.choice([1, 2], size=(10,))})
```

here is what I tried:

```
df.pivot_table(df, values='web1a', index='age', aggfunc='mean')
```

but it is not efficient and didn't produce my desired output. Any idea to get this done? Thanks

**update**:

for me, the way to do this, first select categorical values in each column and get mean for it which can be the same for others. If I do that, how can I nicely plot them?

Note that in column `web1a`,`web1b`, `web1c`, `web1d`, `1` mean user and `2` means non-user respectively. I want to compute the average age of the user and non-user. How can I do that? Anyone give me a possible idea to make this happen? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using

```
df.melt('age').set_index(['variable','value']).mean(level=[0,1]).unstack().plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

Comment: this is awesome, how can I modify legend, title?

Comment: @beyond_inifinity hope the link can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149428/modify-the-legend-of-pandas-bar-plot

Comment: @beyond_inifinity is the link clear enough ? Or what you want to call them

Comment: why it generates default title? how can I rename it? also I want to label blue barplot as user, and orange barplot as non-user, how can I do that? I will accept this awesome solution, thank you !

Comment: @beyond_inifinity try with `df.melt('age').set_index(['variable','value']).age.mean(level=[0,1]).unstack().rename(columns={1:'user',2:'none-user'}).plot(kind='bar')
`

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using `groupby` method:

```
df.groupby(['web1a', 'web1b', 'web1c', 'web1d']).mean()
```

Comment: how can I plot them either with barplot or piechart? seems output of this code is a bit confusing I do plot for them?

Comment: `df.groupby(['web1a', 'web1b', 'web1c', 'web1d']).mean().reset_index().plot.bar(y='age')` 
But you will need to adjust x-axis labels manually.

Answer (score 2):

You can groupby the 'web*' columns and calculate the mean on the 'age' column.

You can also plot bar charts (colors can be defined in the subplot). I'm not sure pie charts make sense in this case.

I tried with your [data](https://jumpshare.com/v/s2WRGzoJHXkrlt3S27Ak), taking only the columns starting with 'web'. There are more values than '1's and '2's, So I assumed you only wanted to analyze the users and non-users and nothing else. You can change the values or add other values in the chart in the same way, as long as you know what values you want to draw.

```
df = df.filter(regex=('web|age'),axis=1)

userNr = '1'
nonUserNr = '2'
users = list()
nonUsers = list()
labels = [x for x in df.columns.tolist() if 'web' in x]
for col in labels:
    users.append(df.loc[:,['age',col]].groupby(col).mean().loc[userNr][0])
    nonUsers.append(df.loc[:,['age',col]].groupby(col).mean().loc[nonUserNr][0])

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
x = np.arange(1, len(labels)+1)
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.bar(x-0.1, users, width=0.2,color='g')
ax.bar(x+0.1,nonUsers, width=0.2,color='r')
plt.xticks(x, labels)
plt.legend(['users','non-users'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
df.melt(id_vars='age').groupby(['variable', 'value']).mean()
```

[image]

Comment: Is that possible to make piechart or pie chart for your input code? Thanks

Comment: There is no meaning in a pie chart where slice sizes are proportional to ages. Use a bar chart instead by adding `.plot.bar()`

Comment: if use bar plot, how to assign a different color for each subgroup in `web1a`? Is there any elegant way to visualize them better create subplot for each group?

Comment: Add this instead: `.unstack().plot.bar()`