# Matplotlib barchart legend only shows one item

Tags: python, matplotlib

When creating a legend for a barchart plot, only the first element of the list is added to the legend.

I have tried to print the legend by means of a grouped dataframe, the barchart is an histogram of occurrence

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'mod': biomarkers})
counts =df.groupby('mod', as_index=False)
counts.size().plot(kind='bar',width=1.0)

names = np.array(counts.describe())[:,2]
counts = np.array(counts.describe())[:,3]
plt.legend(list(names))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Indeed, one barchart with n bars gives one legend entry. If you want n legend entries you need to [create them](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html) yourself or plot n bar plots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Displaying data from pd.DataFrame:

- legend = column names
- x_tics = index

You can convert `counts` Series to DataFrame and transpose.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df = pd.DataFrame({'mod': ['a','b','c','a','a','c']})
counts = df.groupby('mod', as_index=False)

counts_df = counts.size().to_frame().T
counts_df.plot(kind='bar', width=1.0, ax=ax)
# without plt.legend()
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33150133/12166085) and [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html).