# How to change the elements of legend in matplotlib pyplot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm using this code for the line plot of two dataframes. Each df has the MultiIndex columns, Month and Day, and the Values column (the Values are different  in the 2 dataframes whilst Month and Day are the same).

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
ax = plt.gca()

line1=mintemp.plot(kind='line',y='Values',color='blue', legend=False, ax=ax)

line2=maxtemp.plot(kind='line',y='Values', color='darkorange', legend=False, ax=ax)

plt.legend(loc=8, frameon=False, title='Temperatures')
```

I'm not sure how to subscribe the two legend elements as 'Low' and 'High', because they still remain named 'Values'.

I have tried `plt.legend([line1, line2], ['Low', 'High'])` which did not work.

[image: My line plot]

[image: df(1of2)]

P.S. another method, 
`lines=plt.plot(maxtemp.index, maxtemp.Values,,  mintemp.index, mintemp.Values,label='High')`
did not work because

`ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)`

Comment: Just `plt.legend(["Min", "Max"], loc=8, frameon=False, title='Temperatures')`. See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149428/modify-the-legend-of-pandas-bar-plot/33150133).  Note that you're not directly using matplotlib's `plot`, but pandas'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modify the legend of pandas bar plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149428/modify-the-legend-of-pandas-bar-plot)

Comment: It worked! I put ["Min", "Max"] in like you said.  thank you, I did not realise its as simple as this!