# changing the parameters of bargraph in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I was changing the width, colour of individual bars in multiple bars in bar graph.

[image: the dataframe is like this]

This is my dataframe.

The question is not actually a homework question ,but a real problem I am facing.

There are methods in documentaion using which I can adjust the parameter in multiple bar, bargraph. But they are lengthy.

I have made the bargraph using " df1.plot.bar() " this command. df1 is the name of the dataframe.
and I have got a bar graph like this.

[image: Multiple bargraph]

After using this command I was not able to change its width and color . all the methods for changing these parameter has been in matplotlib,  but I have made the graph using pandas library. Now I am facing problems in changing parameters in graph and legends and all.  Now How can I apply parameters of matplotlib in this bargraph?

please don't use backend() approach. I am a novice in data visualisation.

Comment: IIUC, you can do `df1.plot.bar(width=0.9, color=['red', 'blue', 'orange'])` for example...

Comment: thnx for your help , how can i change the legends

Comment: You can't edit legends within the plot.bar method, but check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149428/modify-the-legend-of-pandas-bar-plot/33150133)