# Plot bar chart in python using csv data in pandas & Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

My bar chart is not showing correctly. I have csv data as below. I would like to plot bar chart using group by date and categories Key value with Count. So, every date will be group by and it will categories the key value with their Count. Please assist with below code. I am new and learning python myself.

My csv `collect_data.csv` data:

```
Date,Key,Count
14-10-2020,created,5
14-10-2020,moved,3
14-10-2020,modified,3
14-10-2020,deleted,5
17-10-2020,created,25
17-10-2020,moved,6
17-10-2020,modified,13
17-10-2020,deleted,25
18-10-2020,created,13
18-10-2020,modified,7
18-10-2020,moved,1
18-10-2020,deleted,13
```

My current bar chart:

[image: My current bar chart]

My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

def display_dashboard():
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv("collect_data.csv")
        df.head()
        df['Date'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')

        plt.title('File System Changed Based on Type of Event')
        plt.ylabel('Total Count of Event Occurred')
        plt.xlabel("DATE")

        plt.show()

    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Exception error: Missing files!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you need to reshape your df first:

```
df.set_index(["Date", "Key"]).unstack("Key").plot(kind="bar", rot=0)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is what I need and your suggestion. I am learning and applying those to my code.

Comment: if I want to change the colour of the graph, how can I do that and can we display the total count report on the right corner in the graph?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927715/how-to-give-a-pandas-matplotlib-bar-graph-custom-colors) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149428/modify-the-legend-of-pandas-bar-plot).