# How to add a legend from class labels in dataframe with matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot the rows in a dataframe with labels as a legend. The goal is to have a legend with 4 labels. If I use the command `df.T.plot()` I can see all the curves in one plot correctly but instead of the index in the legend I want to have the plots color coded in ***groups*** like the labels (***class1, class2, class3, class4***).

My dataframe df is something like this:

```
    col1    col2    col3    ...      labels

1   0.12    0.53    0.41    ...      class1
2   0.12    0.51    0.46    ...      class2
3   0.12    0.53    0.43    ...      class2
4   0.12    0.54    0.41    ...      class1
5   0.12    0.53    0.41    ...      class4
6   0.12    0.65    0.63    ...      class3
7   0.12    0.53    0.41    ...      class4
8   0.12    0.52    0.43    ...      class1
```

Example:

```
df.iloc[:, :-1].T.plot()
```

I got this:

[Dataframe rows plot with index as legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xqsb.png)

I have tried to work with the keyword legend and color maps, but could not find a solution that works. I also tried to implement the same directly in matplotlib, but could not solve the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modify the legend of pandas bar plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149428/modify-the-legend-of-pandas-bar-plot)

Comment: Thank you, but I tried modifying the pandas legend parameter before.